# Content-type issue for email attachments mule

Tags: email, mule, imap, email-attachments

I'm using Mule's IMAP connector to read email attachments. I pretty much follow [this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/imap-transport-reference). It all works fine, but my problem is that there are couple of end users who now tend to send the emails with attachments to us, but with Content-type as 'text/csv' or 'application/octet-stream' in which case Mule is unable to recognise/parse the attachments. The email client like outlook has no problems downloading the files. But does not work with Mule code - probably, the content-type to be blamed but is there a way I can get over this without demanding a change from the end user?

Here is the code that reads the attachments:

```
<expression-transformer doc:name="Read Attachments and set them as payload"
        name="returnAttachments">
        <return-argument evaluator="attachments-list"
            expression="*" />
    </expression-transformer>

<imaps:inbound-endpoint host="${email.server.host}"
            port="${email.port}" responseTimeout="10000"
            doc:name="IMAP" connector-ref="IMAPS" password="${email.pwd}"
            transformer-refs="returnAttachments" user="${email.user}"
            disableTransportTransformer="true" />
    <!-- The code below does not work when the emails arrived have content type other the "multipart/mixed"-->
        <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="#[groovy:payload.name]"
            doc:name="fileName" />
```

As mentioned this one recognises the email and attachments when the content type(header) of the email is "mutipart/mixed". Does not work otherwise. Should I be asking the client to set the content type ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not explain what exactly you're trying to do. You can send *anything* through e-mail. Each attachment is marked with a corresponding MIME type to indicate what sort of data **format** it contains -- is that an image, or a ZIP file, or perhaps a PDF document?

What is your application doing, and what reaction do you expect when I send, say, a holiday picture as an attachment? What should it do if I attach my bank's statement?

These questoins are about the business logic, about the real **purpose** of your project. This question does not contain any data about that, unfortunately.

Comment: Think I've been clear enough. If you read this -"I'm using Mule's IMAP connector to read email attachments. I pretty much follow this. It all works fine, but my problem is that there are couple of end users who now tend to send the emails with attachments to us, but with Content-type as 'text/csv' or 'application/octet-stream' in which case Mule is unable to recognize/parse the attachments." You will understand that I'm trying to parse email attachments received via IMAP endpoint. As said, problem is the mule cannot recognise the email attachments when the content type is not "multipart/mixed"

Comment: What do you want/expect Mule (or your code) to do with a CSV file, then? (Since you mention text/csv as a mishandled mime type.)

Comment: I want it to be able to recognise them. I've included code (as opposed to a link) for better understanding. Please advise.

Comment: Any answers please? @Jan Kundrát where are you now?